# Creating hit counter for website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a website having a masterpage. I want to create a hit counter to record the number of visitor and i found a code and put it in my masterpage. The code is as:
Markup Code:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="counter.ascx.cs" Inherits="counter" %>
<asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Code Behind - C#:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 this.countMe();
 DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
 tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
 lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString();
}
private void countMe()
{
 DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
 tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
 int hits = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());
 hits += 1;
 tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = hits.ToString();
 tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
}
```

An xml file in the root directory to make the code work. The XML file is as:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <counter>
   <count>
      <hits>0</hits>
   </count>
 </counter>
```

But every pages within my website triggers the counter whenever i visit them. Please help me modify this code to trigger the counter only one time by one visitor.

I have decided to put the code on index page only, but still every refresh and every lick to open the index (even while staying on index page) triggers the counter.

Comment: Of course, if two visitors are running the `countMe` method at the same time, it's highly likely that you'll a) get error messages if the I/O happens at the wrong times and/or you'll only end up counting one visit (both read a count of 73, both add 1 to it, both save the updated XML with a count of 74). Any reason you're storing in an XML file?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add a session? I think it's the easiest way for an XML solution, if you saved it to SQL you could have more logic involved.

```
private void countMe()
{
 if(Session["Counted"]==null){
 DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
 tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
 int hits = Int32.Parse(tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString());
 hits += 1;
 tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = hits.ToString();
 tmpDs.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
 Session["Counted"] = "Yes";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the url of the page for the counter to hit the code. Try something like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
   if(url.Contains("index.aspx")
   {
     this.countMe();
   }
   DataSet tmpDs = new DataSet();
   tmpDs.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
   lblCounter.Text = tmpDs.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the solution from Global.ascx File.
Go to code behind of Golobal.ascx.cs in your application.
Declare a variable in Global.Cs File.
And Maintain a Count in 'Session_Start' Function Of Global.ascx.cs file;
write some public method to get user count

Eg:

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  totalNumberOfUsers += 1;
  currentNumberOfUsers += 1;
}


protected void Session_End(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  currentNumberOfUsers -= 1;
}

public static int TotalNumberOfUsers
{
  get
  {
    return totalNumberOfUsers;
  }
}

public static int CurrentNumberOfUsers
{
  get
  {
    return currentNumberOfUsers;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using "Session" as in prospectors example, due to the possibility of synchronization issues , don't forget to lock the DataSet before use.

```
private static readonly object LockObj = new object();
private static DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Counted"] == null)
    {
        lock (LockObj)
        {
            dataSet.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
            dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"] = (1 + int.Parse(dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["hits"].ToString())).ToString();
            dataSet.WriteXml(Server.MapPath("~/counter.xml"));
            dataset.clear();
        }
        Session["Counted"] = "true";               
    }
}
```