# How to display auto increment number when same web page opened by 3 different users

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

in our project we are using auto increment number for serial number to show in a textbox. But if the same page is been opened by three different users the same number is being displayed in the textbox. So, is it possible to show for example, if user1 opened the page first then 1, user2 opens the same page then 2, user3 opens the same page then 3. Please provide solution for this issue.

Comment: "in our project we are using auto increment number for serial number to show in a textbox". Show your code.

Comment: Show us what code you are using for incrementing and where the value which is populated to textbox

Comment: Are you looking for hit count kind of stuff? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647318/creating-hit-counter-for-website

Comment: you can also check this [link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2013/11/aspnet-count-number-of-online-users.html)